# ionic 5: Keep youtube iframe video playing when app is in background

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic5, youtube-iframe-api

In Ionic 5, Is there a way to keep playing youtube iframe video when we put app in background. Because when app goes to background the iframe video gets paused.

Can anyone please provide any solution to this?

Comment: i think there is no way to run any process on background in ionic app.. may be native function or native library help you

Comment: @RahulJograna Thank you for the reply. Currently I am using @ionic-native/background-mode plugin to play audio in background and it is working perfect. But it is not working for youtube iframe.